# sql server text fields seem to be taking up a lot of space

Tags: database, text, offline

I don't have full-text indexing set up, but my text fields seem to be taking up a lot of space. It just doesn't 'feel' right.

Is it better to move text fields offline as files in the file system?

Comment: "but my text fields seem to be taking up a lot of space" - what does that mean?

Comment: It's not a scientific thing. I have a couple hundred thousand of them, so maybe the large size is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your text fields are indexed, they've no reason to take up much more space than what they contain (i.e. byte length + some overhead, minus applicable compression applied by your database engine).